# Reading .seq file with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video, toolbox

I downloaded and installed the toolbox that I found on [this site](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/toolbox/doc/)
that is recommended from caltech for manipulating a .seq file. I am trying to open a .seq file using the functions that are in the toolbox.

Reading the instructions from [here](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/toolbox/doc/index.html)
for how to execute a specific mode of the function I see that `sr = seqIo( fName, 'reader', [cache] )` is to Create interface sr for reading seq files. When i execute it in matlab with the format `sr = seqIo( 'V001.seq', 'r', 2048 );` it extracts an error ->

> Error using seqReaderPlugin>open (line 111)
>   Cannot find MATLAB's source image reader

First of all I am not sure what to put in the [case] field as an argument and second I would very appreciate if someone gave a simple script to read every image of the sequence independently for later processing. I do not know if some else has the same problem.

Just to show you that nothing from the toolbox is working I call the function `info = seqIo( 'V001.seq', 'getInfo' )` and it still has the same results also when using other .seq files.

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking those who created the toolbox, as I doubt many of us have used that toolbox before.  Look at the bottom of the doc page, and it reads: **If you have a question or a suggestion, or if you find a bug, please email me at `pdollar-at-gmail.com`**... so get to it!

Comment: Well, the seqIo function that is included in this toolbox is exactly the same that i found in many sites. It is a known function if somebody tried to read .seq files...

Comment: Well I don't know it so you can't generalize it that way!... which brings me back to where we started.  Contact the original author.  Good luck!

Comment: Your matlab must have Image Toolbox for this toolbox to work. Also check if this toolbox is compatible with your version of matlab.

Comment: Well i have Matlab 2014b and Image Processing Toolbox is by default installed with it (http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/release-notes.html), as for the version it says 2011b or later...

Comment: Type `which imread` ... if it returns `imread not found` you're likely not to have necessary toolbox ... Or you can put a breakpoint at line 83 (or line 91) in `~\videos\seqReaderPlugin.m` to further investigate by yourself what's going on.

Comment: Well as i said. The image processing toolbox is already installed. Because this is a ready to use toolbox i dont know if i modified it that will work correctly, the mistake is somewhere else, but i don't know where...

Comment: @monakons - Just because you have MATLAB R2014b **does not** mean you have the image processing toolbox installed.  That link you pointed to only shows the release notes per version of MATLAB.  This is **assuming** you have the toolbox installed.  Please follow CitizenInsane's suggestion and type in `which imread` in the Command Prompt and push ENTER.  If it says it can't find the command, you don't have it installed.  There isn't anything more else to say.

Comment: I know what imread does and if i have image processing toolbox installed. My work is on Computer Vision. Just to show that i have it installed when i type which imread it returns me the path. I contacted the creator of the toolbox and said me that maybe it is the operation system or the version of Matlab that i use. I am not available of changing the operation system nor the Matlab version for a toolbox. I tried different toolbox that reads the .seq file and does not response correctly. So i may ask is there a general way to read .seq files with matlab? any way that is supported?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i contacted the creator and told me to test the toolbox with different types of matlab versions and different operation systems. Worked with windows 7 32-bit and Matlab r2014b.

Comment: This isn't an answer. At best it is a comment or an edit to your original question.

Comment: It is an answer, the toolbox has compatibility issues, even the creator suggested that as a solution and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the function show the message is because the toolbox did not compile correctly.
I encountered the same problem.
Follow these steps to get it running:

```
addpath(genpath('toolbox/folder/location'));
toolboxCompile;
% this should suffice
```

Another problem, everytime you open matlab, unless the toolbox is in the current folder of the workspace, you have to repeat the compilation process.
So instead:

```
pathtool
% a window should appear
```

Click on "Add with subfolders" and select the toolbox subfolder and click save.
You should not have to do the addpath(genpath()); step again.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem and already solved it.

For my cases, it's because I used the university's PC and not be an administrater. Inside the code 'SeqReaderPlugin.m' line 85 , there is a 'copyfile' function, which can only been run by the administer.

So I open the matlab again as an administrater and it works now. (I am using matlab 2018b win64, windows 10)